# When $\frac 1 n \sum^n_{k=1} a_k \to 0 \implies \sum \frac 1 k a_k<+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the statement
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac 1 n \sum^n_{k=1} a_k=0 \implies \sum^{+\infty}_{k=1} \frac 1 k a_k<+\infty
$$

1. Is the statement true for $a_k$ such that $\left|{\frac 1 n \sum^n_{k=1} a_k}\right|<\frac 1 {n^\alpha}$ and $\alpha>0$?
2. Is the statement false in general?

(This is not homework, I think I solved this, it is a nice exercise and I would like to have a feedback)

Comment: Side note.  The other direction $\Longleftarrow$ is Kronecker's Lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma .

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $a_k=\frac{1}{\log(k)}$.  Then, using the [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), we find that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\log(k)}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\log(k)}-\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\log(k)}}{(n+1)-n}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\log(n+1)}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

On the other hand, using the integral test, we see that

$$\begin{align}\int_2^L \frac{1}{x\log(x)}\,dx&=\log(\log(L))-\log(\log(2))\\\\
&\to \infty\,\,\text{as}\,\,L\to \infty
\end{align}$$

and the series $\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k\log(k)}$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Dr.MV's answer covers 2. For 1. use Abel's summation formula (a.k.a. summation by parts):
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\,a_k=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^na_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^ka_j\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac1k-\frac{1}{k+1}\Bigr).
$$
Then
$$
\Bigl|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\,a_k\Bigr|\le n^{-(1+\alpha)}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k}{k^{1+\alpha}(k+1)}<\infty.
$$

Comment: @julianaguiree Julian, nice to see you back!   And solid use of summation by parts. +1